# Android Gradle 2.5 how to get resConfigs "nodpi" to work

Tags: android, build.gradle

Gradle 2.5, [resourceConfigurations << "en"; "in-rID"; "id"; "th"; ] is OK, but when I try to set [resourceConfigurations << "nodpi"; "hdpi"; "xhdpi"; "xxhdpi"; "xxxhdpi";] , it shows [When using splits in tools 21 and above, resConfigs should not contain any densities. Right now, it contains "nodpi"
  Suggestion: remove these from resConfigs from build.gradle], I just want to zip the resources needed to the apk

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `resConfigs "nodpi"` line from your `build.gradle` file. It should be somewhere around here:

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        resConfigs "nodpi" <--- REMOVE THIS LINE
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```